# Yosemite blanking NSSearchField when deselected

Tags: macos, nssearchfield

This is new behavior not seen pre-Yosemite.

An NSSearchField contains text (result of searching).  When the user clicks in a neighboring NSTextField, the NSSearchField contents vanish in 10.10, are retained in 10.9 and earlier.  The app gets no NSNotifications of this "focus" change (and none were previously needed).

I haven't found a way to fix this in 10.10, some way to get the NSSearchField contents to show up and stick; they always disappear when the NSTextField is selected.

Any ideas?  I'll submit a Radar if this looks like a Yosemite bug, but I'd rather fix my code.

Thanks!

Comment: Does it matter if you hit Return before switching to the other text field? I'm wondering if the search has been initiated or if it thinks the user is canceling the search before initiating it.

Comment: The search field is refreshed at return, the I-bar remains blinking at the end of the string.  At a second return, the search field is selected.  Then clicking in a neighboring text filed, the search field is cleared.

Comment: On 10.9 the behavior is identical EXCEPT that the search field is not cleared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, fixed in Preview 8.  :-)